# More elegant way to copy properties in Python 3

Tags: python, optimization, properties

In a Python game I'm writing, I have two classes; ShipType, and Ship. A Ship object represents a specific spaceship with its own name, age, inventory, etc... A ShipType object represents a 'line' of ships (like the Mazda Protege is a 'line' of cars), with its own name, base stats for a ship of that type, Kelley Bluebook In Space prices, etc.

The constructor for Ship takes a ShipType as an argument, since all Ship-s should be derived from a ShipType. That constructor looks like this:

```
...
def __init__(self,theshiptype):
    if not isinstance(theshiptype,ShipType):
        raise TypeError
    self.name=theshiptype.name
    self.inventory=Inventory(theshiptype.invslots)
    self.maxhp=theshiptype.maxhp
    self.thrust=theshiptype.thrust
    self.ftlspeed=theshiptype.ftlspeed
    ...
```

As you can see, the majority of what's going on in this constructor is just copying identically-named properties from the passed object to self. What I'm wondering is, is there a shorter way to do this?

It's worth noting that there are some properties on a ShipType that shouldn't be on a Ship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
attrsToCopy = ['name', 'inventory', 'maxhp', 'thrust', 'ftlspeed']
for attr in attrsToCopy:
    setattr(self, attr, getattr(theshiptype, attr))
```

The `getattr` and `setattr` functions let you get/set attributes whose names are stored in strings.  So you can specify the list of names of attributes to copy, and then copy them concisely by looping over the list.